# Converting free-text user replies to datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am trying to figure out a clever way to take a user's input and store it in a database to be retrieved at a later date.

For context, this is a Discord bot where I am trying to track users' schedules. The idea is that the user could say "&addtime 12/30/1 12pm CST" and the bot would record that they will be online at 12/30/1/ at 12pm CST

The reason I want to track the timezone is so I can convert all the timezones to a specific timezone so that timezones wont get confused.

So after someone adds their time above, if I (someone PST), goes to retrieve when people will be online, I can type "&schedules PST" and get all of the times in the specified timezone.

The problem I'm facing now is all of the datetime examples I can find online all take very exact and specific input. I'm looking for a more forgiving function that is smart enough to figure out datetimes.

Comment: you want `dateutil.parser`

Comment: I found that, but it seems to be unable to handle 'MST, PST, CST, and EST'. It requires much longer, less user friendly timezones. I could map 'MST PST CST and EST' to the longer timezones I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with this method. it only supports US timezones, but that was enough for my needs:

```
from dateutil import parser
from dateutil import tz
import pytz    

def parse_date(self, msg):
        ET = tz.gettz('US/Eastern')
        CT = tz.gettz('US/Central')
        MT = tz.gettz('US/Mountain')
        PT = tz.gettz('US/Pacific')
        us_tzinfos = {'CST': CT, 'CDT': CT,
                      'EST': ET, 'EDT': ET,
                      'MST': MT, 'MDT': MT,
                      'PST': PT, 'PDT': PT}

        usertime = parser.parse(msg, tzinfos=us_tzinfos)
        servertime = usertime.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Phoenix"))

parse_date("12/30/20 12pm EST")
```